# Matlab nlinfit error

Tags: matlab

I'm getting the following error in MATLAB and I'm not able to interpret it completely and ascertain what is the cause. I'm using the `fitnlm` function

Help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Error using nlinfit>checkFunVals (line 636)
The function you provided as the MODELFUN input has returned Inf or NaN values.

Error in nlinfit>LMfit (line 583)
if funValCheck && ~isfinite(sse), checkFunVals(r); end

Error in nlinfit (line 276)
[beta,J,~,cause,fullr] = LMfit(X,yw, modelw,beta,options,verbose,maxiter);

Error in NonLinearModel/fitter (line 1123)
nlinfit(X,y,F,b0,opts,wtargs{:},errormodelargs{:});

Error in classreg.regr.FitObject/doFit (line 220)
model = fitter(model);

Error in NonLinearModel.fit (line 1430)
model = doFit(model);

Error in fitnlm (line 94)
model = NonLinearModel.fit(X,varargin{:});
```

Is this error only due to the input data being non differentiable at certain points for the model function ?

Comment: We cannot possibly answer this without having access to your function and data. You should type `dbstop if error` in the MATLAB command window, and re-run the function until this error occurs. Then MATLAB will have stopped in debug mode inside the function where the error occurred, and then you can inspect all the values of all variables and find out what the cause of this behavior is.